# Embedding of half open half closed set in n-space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, geometric-topology

Edited: (After comments)

Let $n\geq 2$. Let $\Sigma= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: 1\leq |x|<2\}$. Assume $h:\Sigma 
\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and injective. Must $h$ also be an embedding?

Is this a true statement?

Remarks:

1. $h|_{int\Sigma}$ is an embedding.
2. $h(int\Sigma)$ is open.
3. If $h$ defined on $\overline{\Sigma}$ then YES.
4. If $\dim \Sigma <n$ then NO. Consider $\alpha:[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $\alpha(t)=(cos(2\pi t),sin(2\pi t))$.
5. The map $h|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ is an embedding.

The reason $h|_{int \Sigma}$ is an embedding is from invariance of domain, which states:

If $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous injective map and $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $f(U)$ is open and $f$ is homeomorphism onto image .

The reason $h|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ is an embedding is because $h$ is continuous and $K=\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is compact. So, $h|_{K}$ must be an embedding.

Observe $h(\Sigma)=h(int \Sigma)\coprod h(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$.

Comment: This set $\Sigma$ is not clopen, although I can see why you might have said that

Comment: Why are you sure it restricts to an embedding in the interior?

Comment: @FShrike Interior of $\Sigma$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Injective functions between open sets aren’t guaranteed to be embeddings (right?)

Comment: @FShrike these are embeddings by the invariance of domain.

Comment: @freakish oh cool, I didn't know that part of the statement (I've always had invariance of domain in my head as the theorem which says, if two nonempty open subsets of Euclidean space are homeomorphic then their dimension must be the same, but now I realise the theorem is much stronger than that)

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454166/embedding-of-half-open-half-closed-n-set-in-n-space In general, you should wait for about a week before cross-posting, in order to avoid duplication of efforts.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see! Thanks for telling me Moishe!